# How to handle SQL triggers in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, triggers

I have a `User` entity in my Symfony2/Doctrine2 webapp. This user has an attribute `last_updated` to identify the latest time, anything has changed. I set this attribute to `NOT NULL` in my database. So far, so good.

I would consider it to be good practice to create a SQL trigger in the database, that sets this `last_updated` to `NOW()` on every `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. So you don't have to care about this in your application. So that's what I did, I implemented this trigger in my database.

But if I now create a user in my app

```
$user = new User();
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

I get an error message by Symfony:

> An exception occurred while executing `'INSERT INTO User (username, ..., last_updated) VALUES (?, ..., ?)'`
>   with params `["johndoe", ..., null]:`
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column `'last_updated'` cannot be null

The problem is clear: Symfony is trying to fire an `INSERT`-statement to the database with the parameter `null` for `last_updated`, which is not allowed - as this attribute may not be null.

I could quickly think of two workarounds:

- One workaround would be to take the `last_updated` field out of the entity description. Then Symfony would not try to pass anything to the database for this column, and the trigger would set the appropriate value. But I don't think this is a good way, because as soon as I would try to update the db schema (`doctrine:schema:update --force`) I would loose my `last_updated`-column.
- Another workaround: Simply do `$user->setLastUpdated(new \DateTime())` before I `persist()` and `flush()`. But this would minimize the advantage of using a trigger on my database to avoid having to care about it in my application.

Is there any way to let Symfony/Doctrine know that there is a trigger running on my database? If not, (how) can I hook into Symfony/Doctrine to implement a proper workaround?

Comment: You can read about Lifecycle Callbacks - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks, I think it would be usefull.

Comment: Thanks, good idea. So triggers on the db layer are off the table here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To quote a response to this question from a google group:

> Database side code (such as Triggers and Functions) tend to break the benefits of developing software using an ORM like Propel or Doctrine as one of the biggest advantages of using ORM's is to be database agnostic. By having database side Triggers and Functions you are tying yourself to the database and therefore gain little to no benefit using an ORM. -GarethMc

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony-users/MH_ML9Dy0Rw

For this it is best to use the Life Cycle Callbacks as Faery suggests. One simple function will handle updating that field so that you dont have to worry about it if you decide to change databases in the future.

```
//In Your Entity File EX: SomeClass.php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class SomeClass
{
    ....

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function prePersistPreUpdate()
    {
        $this->last_modified = new \DateTime();
    }
}
```

See also references for lifecycle callbacks

- [Symfony reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/lifecycle_callbacks.html)
- [Doctrine reference](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events)

In your case you would add the lifecycle call back function and annotation to your User entity class. SomeClass is simply an example class showing that lifecycle callbacks are good for more than just your User entity.

Answer (score 5):

Another (easier and more generalized) option would be to use the `Timestampable` Doctrine extension by Gedmo. In this way, you could simply annotate your entity fields to be timestamped on create or on update.

Example:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

class MyEntity
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var \DateTime $lastUpdated
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_updated", type="datetime")
     */
    private $lastUpdated;

    ...
}
```

https://packagist.org/packages/gedmo/doctrine-extensions

Comment: Since I posed my question, I tumbled upon Gedmo and love timestampable as well as orthers (loggable is another killer plugin!). So thanks for mentioning it here!